# How to reference a symbol's components inside the symbol's constructor?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

What I did:
A draged some components to the stage (e.g: a label, and a button), selected them togeather and (f8) made a symbol out of them. (Ticked the "Export for AS3" checkbox.) Inside the symbol, I gave each one of them instance names.

What I want:
I'd like to have a class for my symbol with a constructor, that sets the symbol's components to the given parameters. For example:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class MySymbol extends MovieClip {

   public function MySymbol(pX :int, pY :int, name :String) {
      this.labelInstName.text = name;
      this.buttonInstName.x = pX;
      this.buttonInstName.y = pY;
   }

}

// call constructor in an other class
var ms :MySymbol = new MySymbol(10, 10, "My label text");
```

.y, .x attributes work, but .text and .value don't. Why? Am I referencing the symbol with "this" incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: What is the result of `trace(labelInstName);` in the constructor?

Comment: the result is: [object Label]

Comment: Do you use a special font in the label?

Comment: maybe not special font but just not embedded

Comment: it works fine if it's not in the symbol's class. But in here, nothing happens, not even an error message.

Comment: A workaround I've found is to pass the symbol itself in the construcor and store as a class attribute (private var _self :MySymbol;) - later use the components as this._self.labelInstName.text = "Works". But this way, I can't set up the symbol only using the constructor - which is inconvenient.